# Invoke external program and pass arguments

Tags: fortran

I am writing a Fortran program that is to invoke a previously written program. Essentially, my program will create an input file and invoke the external program. The input file will then be read by the external program which will compute a set of data and generate and output file. My program will then read this output file.

I am able to invoke the external program using `CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE("FILENAME")`. However, the external program requests an input file name.

How do I pass the input file name to a program invoked within Fortran?

Comment: What about `CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE("FILENAME "//file_name) `?

Comment: Does the external program take the file's name as a command line argument or read from its standard input (or some other mechanism)?

Comment: Try: call execute_command_line("echo '"//INPUTFILENAME//"' | FILENAME"). This works if the external program reads the input from the command line. (It passes echo 'INPUTFILENAME' | FILENAME) to the command line) If the external program requests the input filename as an argument, do what @Vladimir suggests.

Comment: Passing the input through echo doesn't work if the thing I'm printing has quotes in it, and it doesn't work if I don't have the thing to be copied in a single string, eg if I'm printing as I iterate.